# Servlet returns text and not HTML

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

```
$(document).ready(function() {                        
     $.get('Navigation', function(responseText) { 
           $('#navi').text(responseText);         
     });
});
```

I am calling a servlet named 'Navigation' in order to get the result in the div with the id 'navi'. The servlet works fine. I get the code in the div but it is shown as a text and not rendered as HTML-code.

EDIT:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    dao = new WebshopDAO();

    kategorien = dao.gibKategorien();

    out.println("<ul>");
    for (Katalog k1 : kategorien) {  
        Integer oberKat = k1.getOberkategorieNr();
        if (oberKat == 0) {
        out.println("<li class='has-sub'><a>" + k1.getKName() + "</a>\n");
            for (Katalog k2 : kategorien) {
                if (Objects.equals(k2.getOberkategorieNr(), k1.getKategorieNr())) {
                    out.println("<ul>\n<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='"
                               + k2.getKategorieNr() + "'>" + k2.getKName() + "</button></form></a></li>\n</ul>\n");
                }
            }
        out.println("</li>\n");                
        }          
    } 
    out.println("</ul>");
}
```

EDIT2 :

```
    <li class='has-sub'><a>Lebensmittel</a>
<ul>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='5'>Reis</button></form></a></li>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='6'>Gewürze</button></form></a></li>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='7'>Tee</button></form></a></li>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='8'>Snacks</button></form></a></li>

</ul></li>


<li class='has-sub'><a>Küche & Haushalt</a>
<ul>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='9'>Reiskocher</button></form></a></li>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='10'>Besteck</button></form></a></li>

</ul></li>


<li class='has-sub'><a>Bücher</a>
<ul>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='13'>Geschichte</button></form></a></li>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='14'>Sprachen</button></form></a></li>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='15'>Reiseführer</button></form></a></li>

</ul></li>


<li class='has-sub'><a>Sonstiges</a>
<ul>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='16'>T-Shirts</button></form></a></li>

<li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='17'>Poster</button></form></a></li>

</ul></li>
```

EDIT 3:

It seems like that the servlet does not see the CSS, so I cannot open the category. How can I tell my servlet to add the CSS if it does not have Head tag?

Comment: Where are the css files hosted? You still need to serve that content from somewhere. Either create a servlet that serves it dynamically or depending on what you are using there should already be a standard folder for static assets like images, html and css files.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding <script src='script.js'></script> in my servlets out.println. Can someone explain me why i have to do it, and why it is not enough to have it on my index.html only?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.html()`,

`.text()` treats input string as Plain Text; `html()` treats it as HTML.

```
$('#navi').html(responseText);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I expected. The problem is tht it didn't work somehow. I added my servlet code. The problem might lay within the servlet. Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean the last line out.println("</ul>"); or the entire HTML ?

Comment: Add `console.log(responseText)` inside `function(responseText){}` and see what it prints in the console. Add that to your answer

Comment: Where can I see the log?

Comment: In the Developer console of your browser. For ex. Press F12 in Google Chrome and click on console.

Comment: Well, i changed the <div id="navi"> ..</div> to <ul id="navi> ..</ul> and now I get my categories inside the navigation. Next problem is that it doesnt show me the subcategories of my categories, even though my debugger shows that it was correctly printed through out.println(...).

Comment: A supcategory looks like this: <li class='has-sub'><a>Lebensmittel</a>

<ul><li><a><form method='get'><button type='submit' name='category' value='5'>Reis</button></form></a></li></ul>

Comment: The problem might be in the `<ul><li>` if one ending tag `</li>` is missing(in your subcategory) it would render invalid html. Which is wjy I told you to do console.log amd add the output in log to your question above

Comment: OK, I added it now. I cannot open a category now. Through my CSS, I can click on a category and then I see its subcategories. But now I just see the categories and I cannot click on it.

Comment: I am a bit confused. I used JSPs before and used everything I have in my servlet now in the JSP. It was ugly but it worked. Now I use jquery and servlets and now somehow I cannot open a category

Comment: No idea what the problem might be?

Comment: The problem is in the HTML structure. Can you explain more about what do you mean by `open a category`?

Comment: I found out whats wrong. The JS must be added to the servlet as well. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Can use `load()` method which is a shortcut for `$.ajax` as is `$.get` and takes care of the insertion for you

replace your `$.get` with

```
$('#navi').load('Navigation');
```

Otherwise use `html()` method when you are working with html strings